# web3 - how receive values from contract methods

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I have a Solidity contract with a method that changes the state of the contract. This method normally returns a value. But web3 gives me txHash, net the return value. Do I have a way to receive that value?

```
myContract.incrData.sendTransaction(function (err, result) {
    var txhash = result;  // <-- I need return value, not the tx hash
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But web3 gives me txHash, net the return value.

The `sendTransaction` method always returns a transaction hash whether the transaction is to a contract or an account. This is because when you send the transaction, the contract is not executed till mining is done, because of which it cannot get the return values till your transaction is mined.

> Do I have a way to receive that value?

You can use events to get the values from the contract. Details on how to emit events can be found  at https://media.consensys.net/technical-introduction-to-events-and-logs-in-ethereum-a074d65dd61e